# Properly decoding UTF-8 HTML page

Tags: html, mysql, utf-8

Iam experiencing some weird issue with HTML 5, currently i'm retrieving information from a Database on MySQL, the database is encoded using UTF-8, and when i retrieve information without using any HTML markup everything is working fine, but in pages with HTML markup things are not properly working.

- Here is a [page](http://quizu.com.br/v2/) that uses HTML markup
- Here is a [page](http://quizu.com.br/v2/simplequery.php) without any HTML Markup ( Things working well )

The query's are the exact same.

Here is the HEAD information:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="pt-br">
      <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Quizu - Testes de personalidade</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
      <link href="css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="css/bootstrap-social.css" rel="stylesheet">
      <script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.js"></script>
      <script src="js/meu.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

      <link href="css/quizu.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
```

[image: Here is a example of UTF-8 characters being replaced by ?, the text should be "Qual personagem de Dragon Ball você é?"]

Thanks in advance, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Your page without markup is parsed in windows-1252. The page with markup is parsed in UTF-8, because you say so.

Comment: Thats weird, by removing the meta charset=utf-8, everything is working.

Comment: Exactly, because the text is not encoded in UTF-8. Either encode it as UTF-8, or tell the browser which is you encoding.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in my MySQL query, although my Database was encoded in UTF-8, the query was not being made using UTF-8. All i had to do "SET NAMES UTF-8" to my query.

```
$dbHandle = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbHost;dbname=$dbName;charset=utf8", $dbUser, $dbPass,array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES 'utf8'"));
```